# Why VS does not offer creating of MVC Controller using Entitity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I am new to .NET Core and I still trying to get all puzzles together.
One strange thing for me is.
I am using VS2015 CE Update3

When I create new project under 
Visual C# -> Web -> ASP.NET Core Web Application 
And on next form when I Change Authentication to Individual User Accounts 
In my project under Solution Explorer explorer there is context menu on folder Controllers with  give me ability to create new Controller using Entity Framework
[image]

---

If I create same project without changing authentication mode.
[image]
 I do not get ability to create MVC Conntolers using Entity Framework?
Why ?
What I am missing in project whitout autentification to be able to create Scaffold Conntolers and Views

[image]

Even if I install Entity Framework using NuGet according to [ASP.NET Core Docs for Enitity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db) I still do not get ability to Scarfold MVC Conntolers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My apologies for spamming here on SO.
If I did not asked I will not ever find solution
Looks like this is know issue for .NET Core Preview 2 Visual Studio tooling
[There is note on next  docs which I did not not reach because I stacked on line bofore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro)

> Don't miss setting authentication to Individual User Accounts. You
>   won't be using authentication in this tutorial, but you need to enable
>   it because of a limitation of .NET Core Preview 2 Visual Studio
>   tooling. Scaffolding for MVC controllers and views only works when
>   Individual User Accounts authentication is enabled.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to answer your own question. Just make sure to mark it as accepted, once the waiting period is over